# Shape Error Feeding Value for Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to follow [this](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html) guide to implement Keras layers in Tensorflow tensors.

I create the placeholders and model as follows.

```
sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)
K.set_learning_phase(1)

# Initialize placeholders

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(BATCH_SIZE, 160, 320, 6))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])

# Create Model
x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(x)


x = Flatten()(x)

x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
preds = Dense(1)(x)
```

And I run it as follows.

```
with sess.as_default():
    for i in range(EPOCHS):

        for batch in range(len(x_train) // BATCH_SIZE):
            batch_x = x_train[batch * BATCH_SIZE:min((batch + 1) * BATCH_SIZE, len(x_train))]
            batch_y = y_train[batch * BATCH_SIZE:min((batch + 1) * BATCH_SIZE, len(y_train))]

            opt = sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
```

I run into the error " Cannot feed value of shape (8, 160, 320, 6) for Tensor 'dropout_3/dropout/mul:0', which has shape '(?, 256)' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a feed_dict, it doesn't automatically know that you want to feed it into the FIRST x that appears in your class, it could try to feed it anywhere x appears.  In particular, it looks like it's feeding it into the last assignment of x: x = Dropout(0.25)(x).  Since that has size ? x 256, it doesn't work.  In order to fix this, use the following:

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(BATCH_SIZE, 160, 320, 6))
x = input
```

and then in your feed_dict, do

```
feed_dict={input: batch_x, y: batch_y}
```